# Reset Records to 0 on Sunday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So each `@routine` can have one `freebie` and `freebie_date` per week. On 12am Sunday I want the `freebie` to reset back to `0` and the `freebie_date` to reset back to `nil` so that the user has the opportunity to use a freebie for the new week.

I figure in **routine.rb** I need something like this:

```
  def refresh_freebie
    if Date.sunday
     routine.freebie = 0
     routine.freebie_date = nil
    end
  end
```

and then I just don't know how to make `refresh_freebie` to trigger for each `routine` record so that once Sunday hits all the `freebie`'s and `freebie_date`'s go back to nothing.

Thanks for your guidance friends!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a rake task where you will loop through all the `routine`s in your database and reset the `freebie` and `freebie_date` column values to zero. 
And, you can schedule the rake task to run every Sunday. For example, you can schedule a rake task on heroku using [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) plugin. That's it!

Your rake task can look like this:

```
# lib/tasks/routine.rake
namespace :routines do
  desc 'Clean the routine freebies and freebie_dates'
  task clean: :environment do
    return unless Date.today.sunday?
    Routine.all.each do |routine|
      routine.freebie = 0
      routine.freebie_date = nil
      routine.save
    end
  end
end
```

You can make it more efficient by using [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) rather than looping through all the records:

```
Routine.update_all(freebie: 0, freebie_date: nil)
```

So, your rake task becomes:

```
# lib/tasks/routine.rake
namespace :routines do
  desc 'Clean the routine freebies and freebie_dates'
  task clean: :environment do
    return unless Date.today.sunday?
    Routine.update_all(freebie: 0, freebie_date: nil)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So whenever freebie_date is set to some date, freebie hops to 1? I can't really say since I can only see a small fraction of your app, but perhaps it makes sense to remove the freebie altogether? You could write methods on Routine like `can_have_freebie?` or `has_freebee?` just based on freebie_date and the current date. But this is really just an idea, it could be entirely the wrong direction.